# function array(){[native code]} error in javascript timer

Tags: javascript, timer

I'm trying to implement a countdown timer for online examination system.I wrote the following code but it is showing `00:function array(){[native code]}:59` instead of the timer `2:00`. I didn't understand where i went wrong. Below is my code for timer

```
//***********************************************//
//* Online Examination System                   *//
//*---------------------------------------------*//
//*                                             *//
//* Author: chandra sai & omkar                 *//
//* Title:  Count Down Timer                    *//
//***********************************************//


function countDown() {
  sec--;
  if (sec == -01) {
    sec = 59;
    min = min - 1;
    if (min == -01) {
      min = 59;
      hour = hour - 1;
    } else {
      hour = hour;
    }
  } else {
    min = min;
  }
  if (sec <= 9) {
    sec = "0" + sec;
  }

  time = (hour <= 9 ? "0" + hour : hour) + " : " + (min <= 9 ? "0" + min : min) + " : " + sec + "";
  if (document.getElementById) {
    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = time;
  }
  SD = window.setTimeout("countDown();", 1000);
  if (hour == '00' && min == '00' && sec == '00') {
    sec = "00";
    min = "00";
    window.clearTimeout(SD);
    window.location = document.forms[0].action + "?fs=yes";
  }
}

function addLoadEvent(func) {
  var oldonload = window.onload;
  if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
  } else {
    window.onload = function() {
      if (oldonload) {
        oldonload();
      }
      func();
    }
  }
}

addLoadEvent(function() {
  countDown();
});
```

below is the code file where i used this timer:

```
<?php
/*
 * **************************************************
 * ** Online Examination System                   ***
 * **---------------------------------------------***
 * **                                            ***
 * ** Author:chandra sai & omkar                     ***
 * ** Title: Practice Test                        ***
 * **************************************************
 */

error_reporting(0);
session_start();
include_once 'oesdb.php';
$final = false;
if (!isset($_SESSION['stdname'])) {
    $_GLOBALS['message'] = "Session Timeout.Click here to <a href=\"index.php\">Re-LogIn</a>";
} else if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
    //Log out and redirect login page
    unset($_SESSION['stdname']);
    unset($_SESSION['stdid']);
    header('Location: index.php');
} else if (isset($_REQUEST['dashboard'])) {
    //redirect to dashboard
    //
    header('Location: stdwelcome.php');
} else if (isset($_REQUEST['next']) || isset($_REQUEST['fsum'])) {
    //Process first question
    if (isset($_REQUEST['markreview'])) {
        $_SESSION['q1status'] = 'review';
        $_SESSION['q1stdans'] = $_REQUEST['answer'];
    } else {
        $_SESSION['q1status'] = 'answered';
        $_SESSION['q1stdans'] = $_REQUEST['answer'];
    }

    $_SESSION['curqnid'] = 2;
    if (isset($_REQUEST['fsum'])) {
        $_REQUEST['summary'] = "summary";
    }
} else if (isset($_REQUEST['viewsummary']) || isset($_REQUEST['summary'])) {

    //Process Second question

    if (isset($_REQUEST['markreview'])) {
        $_SESSION['q2status'] = 'review';
        $_SESSION['q2stdans'] = $_REQUEST['answer'];
    } else {
        $_SESSION['q2status'] = 'answered';
        $_SESSION['q2stdans'] = $_REQUEST['answer'];
    }

    $_SESSION['curqnid'] = 0;
} else if (!isset($_SESSION['starttime']) && !isset($_REQUEST['finalsubmit'])) {
    //firsttime entry
    $_SESSION['starttime'] = time();
    $_SESSION['curqnid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['q1status'] = "unanswered";
    $_SESSION['q1stdans'] = "unanswered";
    $_SESSION['q2status'] = "unanswered";
    $_SESSION['q2stdans'] = "unanswered";
} else if (isset($_REQUEST['change'])) {
    //redirect to testconducter

    $_SESSION['curqnid'] = substr($_REQUEST['change'], 7);

    //  header('Location: practicetest.php');
} else if (isset($_REQUEST['previous'])) {

    if (isset($_REQUEST['markreview'])) {
        $_SESSION['q2status'] = 'review';
        $_SESSION['q2stdans'] = $_REQUEST['answer'];
    } else {
        $_SESSION['q2status'] = 'answered';
        $_SESSION['q2stdans'] = $_REQUEST['answer'];
    }
    $_SESSION['curqnid'] = 1;
} else if (isset($_REQUEST['summary'])) {
    // nothing to do
} else if (isset($_REQUEST['finalsubmit'])) {
    // nothing to do
} else if (isset($_REQUEST['fs'])) {
    //Final Submission
    header('Location: practicetest.php?finalsubmit=yes');
}
?>
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>OES-Practice</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE"/>
        <meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE"/>
        <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NONE"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="oes.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="validate.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cdtimer.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            <!--
<?php
if (!isset($_REQUEST['finalsumbit']) && isset($_SESSION['starttime'])) {
    $elapsed = (time() - $_SESSION['starttime']);

    if (($elapsed / 60) < 2) {
        echo "var hour=00;";
        if ($elapsed == 0)
            $elapsed = 1;
        echo "min=" . (array) (2 - ($elapsed / 60)) . ";";
        if ($elapsed > 60)
            echo "sec=" . (60 - ($elapsed - 60)) . ";";
        else
            echo "sec=" . (60 - $elapsed) . ";";
    }
    else {
        echo "var hour=0;var min=0;sec=01;";
        unset($_SESSION['starttime']);
    }
}
?>

    -->
        </script>

    </head>
    <body >
        <noscript><h2>For the proper Functionality, You must use Javascript enabled Browser</h2></noscript>
<?php
if ($_GLOBALS['message']) {
    echo "<div class=\"message\">" . $_GLOBALS['message'] . "</div>";
}
?>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="header">
                <img style="margin:10px 2px 2px 10px;float:left;" height="150" width="150" src="images/logo.png" alt="OES"/><h3 class="headtext"> &nbsp;Online Examination System </h3><h4 style="color:#ffffff;text-align:center;margin:0 0 5px 5px;"><i>...because Examination Matters</i></h4>
            </div>
            <form id="practicetest" action="practicetest.php" method="post">
                <div class="menubar">
                    <ul id="menu">
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['stdname'])) {
    // Navigations
    if ($_REQUEST['finalsubmit']) {
?>
                                <li><input type="submit" value="LogOut" name="logout" class="btn btn-primary" title="Log Out"/></li>
                                <li><input type="submit" value="DashBoard" name="dashboard" class="btn btn-primary" title="Dash Board"/></li>

<?php
    }
?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="page">

<?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST['summary']) || isset($_REQUEST['viewsummary'])) {

        $_SESSION['curqnid'] = 0;
        //summary
?>
                    <table border="0" width="100%" class="ntab">
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:40%;"><h3><span id="timer" class="timerclass"></span></h3></th>

                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table cellpadding="30" cellspacing="10" class="datatable">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Question No</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Change Your Answer</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td <?php if (strcmp($_SESSION['q1status'], "review") == 0 || strcmp($_SESSION['q1status'], "unanswered") == 0) {
            echo "style=\"color:#ff0000;\"";
        } ?> > <?php echo $_SESSION['q1status']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Change 1 \" name=\"change\" class=\"ssubbtn\" />"; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td <?php if (strcmp($_SESSION['q2status'], "review") == 0 || strcmp($_SESSION['q2status'], "unanswered") == 0) {
                        echo "style=\"color:#ff0000;\"";
                    } ?> > <?php echo $_SESSION['q2status']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Change 2 \" name=\"change\" class=\"ssubbtn\" />"; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center;"><input type="submit" name="finalsubmit" value="Final Submit" class="subbtn"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
<?php
                } else if (isset($_REQUEST['finalsubmit'])) {
?>
                    <table cellpadding="20" cellspacing="30" border="0" style="background:#ffffff url(images/page.gif);text-align:left;line-height:20px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><h3 style="color:#0000cc;text-align:center;">Test Summary</h3></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" ><hr style="color:#ff0000;border-width:4px;"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Student Name</td>
                            <td><?php echo $_SESSION['stdname']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Test</td>
                            <td>Sample Test</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Subject</td>
                            <td>C programming</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Test Duration</td>
                            <td>00:02:00</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Max. Marks</td>
                            <td>2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Obtained Marks</td>
                            <td><?php
                    $marks = 0;
                    if (strcmp($_SESSION['q1stdans'], "array") == 0)
                        $marks = $marks + 1;
                    if (strcmp($_SESSION['q2stdans'], "DennisRitchie") == 0)
                        $marks = $marks + 1;
                    echo $marks;
?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Percentage</td>
                            <td><?php echo (($marks / 2) * 100) . " %"; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" ><hr style="color:#ff0000;border-width:2px;"/></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><h3 style="color:#0000cc;text-align:center;">Test Information in Detail</h3></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" ><hr style="color:#ff0000;border-width:4px;"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table cellpadding="30" cellspacing="10" class="datatable">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Q. No</th>
                            <th>Question</th>
                            <th>Correct Answer</th>
                            <th>Your Answer</th>
                            <th>Score</th>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>1</td>
                            <td>which of the following is a non-primitive data type</td>
                            <td>int</td>
                            <td><?php echo $_SESSION['q1stdans']; ?></td>
<?php
                    if (strcmp($_SESSION['q1stdans'], "array") == 0) {
                        echo "<td>1</td><td class=\"tddata\"><img src=\"images/correct.png\" title=\"Correct Answer\" height=\"30\" width=\"40\" alt=\"Correct Answer\" /></td>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<td>0</td><td class=\"tddata\"><img src=\"images/wrong.png\" title=\"Wrong Answer\" height=\"30\" width=\"40\" alt=\"Wrong Answer\" /></td>";
                    }
?>


                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>2</td>
                            <td>Who is the creator of "C Programming Language"?</td>
                            <td>Dennis Ritchie</td>
                            <td><?php echo $_SESSION['q2stdans']; ?></td>
<?php
                    if (strcmp($_SESSION['q2stdans'], "DennisRitchie") == 0) {
                        echo "<td>1</td><td class=\"tddata\"><img src=\"images/correct.png\" title=\"Correct Answer\" height=\"30\" width=\"40\" alt=\"Correct Answer\" /></td>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<td>0</td><td class=\"tddata\"><img src=\"images/wrong.png\" title=\"Wrong Answer\" height=\"30\" width=\"40\" alt=\"Wrong Answer\" /></td>";
                    } ?>


                        </tr>
                            <?php
                            unset($_SESSION['starttime']);
                            unset($_SESSION['curqnid']);
                            unset($_SESSION['q1status']);
                            unset($_SESSION['q1stdans']);
                            unset($_SESSION['q2status']);
                            unset($_SESSION['q2stdans']);
                            ?>
                    </table>
<?php
                        }if ($_SESSION['curqnid'] == 2) {
?>
                    <div class="tc">

                        <table border="0" width="100%" class="ntab">
                            <tr>
                                <th style="width:40%;"><h3><span id="timer" class="timerclass"></span></h3></th>
                                <th style="width:40%;"><h4 style="color: #af0a36;">Question No: 2 </h4></th>
                                <th style="width:20%;"><h4 style="color: #af0a36;"><input type="checkbox" name="markreview" value="mark"> Mark for Review</input></h4></th>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <textarea cols="100" rows="8" name="question" readonly style="width:96.8%;text-align:left;margin-left:2%;margin-top:2px;font-size:120%;font-weight:bold;margin-bottom:0;color:#0000ff;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;">Who is the creator of "C Programming Language"?</textarea>
                        <table border="0" width="100%" class="ntab">
                            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                            <tr><td >1. <input type="radio" name="answer" value="DennisRitchie" <?php if ((strcmp($_SESSION['q2status'], "review") == 0 || strcmp($_SESSION['q2status'], "answered") == 0) && strcmp($_SESSION['q2stdans'], "DennisRitchie") == 0) {
                                echo "checked";
                            } ?>> Dennis Ritchie</input></td></tr>
                                <tr><td >2. <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Bjarne" <?php if ((strcmp($_SESSION['q2status'], "review") == 0 || strcmp($_SESSION['q2status'], "answered") == 0) && strcmp($_SESSION['q2stdans'], "Bjarne") == 0) {
                                echo "checked";
                            } ?>> Bjarne Stroustrup</input></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td >3. <input type="radio" name="answer" value="JamesGosling" <?php if ((strcmp($_SESSION['q2status'], "review") == 0 || strcmp($_SESSION['q2status'], "answered") == 0) && strcmp($_SESSION['q2stdans'], "JamesGosling") == 0) {
                                echo "checked";
                            } ?>> James Gosling</input></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td >4. <input type="radio" name="answer" value="KenThompson" <?php if ((strcmp($_SESSION['q2status'], "review") == 0 || strcmp($_SESSION['q2status'], "answered") == 0) && strcmp($_SESSION['q2stdans'], "KenThompson") == 0) {
                                echo "checked";
                            } ?>> Ken Thompson</input></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th style="width:80%;"><h4><input type="submit" name="viewsummary" value="View Summary" class="subbtn"/></h4></th>
                                        <th style="width:12%;text-align:right;"><h4><input type="submit" name="previous" value="Previous" class="subbtn"/></h4></th>
                                        <th style="width:8%;text-align:right;"><h4><input type="submit" name="summary" value="Summary" class="subbtn" /></h4></th>
                                    </tr>

                                </table>
                            </div>
<?php
                        } else if ($_SESSION['curqnid'] == 1) {
?>
                            <div class="tc">

                                <table border="0" width="100%" class="ntab">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th style="width:40%;"><h3><span id="timer" class="timerclass"></span></h3></th>
                                        <th style="width:40%;"><h4 style="color: #af0a36;">Question No: 1 </h4></th>
                                        <th style="width:20%;"><h4 style="color: #af0a36;"><input type="checkbox" name="markreview" value="mark"> Mark for Review</input></h4></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                                <textarea cols="100" rows="8" name="question" readonly style="width:96.8%;text-align:left;margin-left:2%;margin-top:2px;font-size:120%;font-weight:bold;margin-bottom:0;color:#0000ff;padding:2px 2px 2px 2px;">which of the following is a non-primitive data type</textarea>
                                <table border="0" width="100%" class="ntab">
                                    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                                    <tr><td >1. <input type="radio" name="answer" value="array" <?php if ((strcmp($_SESSION['q1status'], "review") == 0 || strcmp($_SESSION['q1status'], "answered") == 0) && strcmp($_SESSION['q1stdans'], "array") == 0) {
                                echo "checked";
                            } ?>> array</input></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td >2. <input type="radio" name="answer" value="string" <?php if ((strcmp($_SESSION['q1status'], "review") == 0 || strcmp($_SESSION['q1status'], "answered") == 0) && strcmp($_SESSION['q1stdans'], "string") == 0) {
                                echo "checked";
                            } ?>> string</input></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td >3. <input type="radio" name="answer" value="int" <?php if ((strcmp($_SESSION['q1status'], "review") == 0 || strcmp($_SESSION['q1status'], "answered") == 0) && strcmp($_SESSION['q1stdans'], "int") == 0) {
                                echo "checked";
                            } ?>> int</input></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td >4. <input type="radio" name="answer" value="char" <?php if ((strcmp($_SESSION['q1status'], "review") == 0 || strcmp($_SESSION['q1status'], "answered") == 0) && strcmp($_SESSION['q1stdans'], "char") == 0) {
                                echo "checked";
                            } ?>> char</input></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th style="width:80%;"><h4><input type="submit" name="next" value="Next" class="subbtn"/></h4></th>
                                        <th style="width:8%;text-align:right;"><h4><input type="submit" name="fsum" value="Summary" class="subbtn" /></h4></th>
                                    </tr>

                                </table>


                            </div>
<?php
                        }
                        closedb();
                    }
?>
                </div>

            </form>
            <div id="footer">
                <p style="font-size:70%;color:#ffffff;"> Developed By-<b>chandra sai & omkar</b><br/> </p><p>Prepared under the guidance of Prof. A.Ananda Rao</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

please help me fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

your answer here:

```
var hours = 1;
var minutes = 0;
var seconds = 0;

var total = (hours * 60 + minutes) * 60 + seconds;
function formatNum(x) {
    var s = "0" + x;
    return s.substr(s.length - 2);
}
function countDown() {
    if (total == 0) window.location=document.forms[0].action+"?fs=yes";
    else {
        var H = parseInt(total / (60 * 60));
        var M = parseInt((total - H * 60 * 60) / 60);
        var S = total - (H * 60 + M) * 60;
        var sTime = formatNum(H) + " : " + formatNum(M) + " : " + formatNum(S);
        console.log(sTime);
        total--;
        setTimeout("countDown()", 1000);    
    }
}
window.load = countDown();
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have assigned `min = Math.min;` somewhere in your code. So when you do:

```
time = (hour <= 9 ? "0" + hour : hour) + " : " + (min <= 9 ? "0" + min : min) + " : " + sec + "";
```

it puts the value of `Math.min.toString()` after the `:`. Since `Math.min` is a built-in function of the browser, its string is `"function array(){[native code]}"`.

So either use a different variable in your countdown code, or find that assignment and get rid of it (and make sure the rest of the code uses `Math.min()` instead of the shortcut version).